# Creating a path with an object id to map with cucumber scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm trying to create a cucumber scenario that checks to see if elements are loaded for an 'edit posting' page. My trouble, however, is that I don't know how to create a path that will direct it to the page.

The general path is something like:   /posting/id/edit 
i.e. /posting/11/edit

Here is my posting.feature scenario

```
# Editing existing post 
Scenario: Saving the edits to an existing post
    Given I am logged in 
    Given there is a posting
    Given I am on the edit posting page
    When I fill in "posting_title" with "blah"
    And I fill in "posting_location" with "blegh"
    When I press "Update posting"
    Then I should see "Posting was successfully updated."
```

I dabbled around with some Factory Girl stuff, but I don't have the knowledge to use it appropriately (if it offers a solution), and wasn't able to find a relevant example.
I've also seen a lot of suggestions with regards to 'Pickle', but if possible I'd like to avoid that route to keep things simple seeing as I have very limited experience.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a link on your website that would take someone to the edit page? Then you could do something like:

```
Given I am on the homepage
And I follow "Posts"
And I follow "Edit"
```

This assumes that there is a link on your homepage whose text is Posts, and then another one in the resulting page called Edit. This is the best way to accomplish this, because there should be a direct route to whatever page you are testing. Those steps are also provided in web_steps.rb

You could also make a custom step like you did there with `Given I am on the edit posting page` and the code would be something like:

```
Given /^I am on the edit posting page$/ do
    visit("/posting/11/edit")
end
```

Which you of course could also generalize like `I am on the edit posting page for posting 11`. But in general, cucumber tests are acceptance tests, which means not bypassing things like this. You should have a link to the edit page that can be clicked.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :) ! I'll try that out (seems like it should work). I actually came up with a solution using Factory Girl, but because my ranking is so low I can't post my solution.. u.u . It'll be another 7 hours before I can.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, but I am not sure of its validity in terms of how clean it is. I ended up using Factory Girl (installed the gem).
I kept my scenario the same.

Under **features/step_definitions** I created **posting_steps.rb**

```
Given /^there is a posting$/ do
    Factory(:posting)
end
```

Under **features/support** I created a file **factories.rb** with the following inside:

```
Factory.define :posting do |f|
  f.association :user
  f.title 'blah'
  f.location 'Some place'
end
```

In my **paths.rb** I used

```
when /the edit posting page/
    edit_posting_path(Posting.first)
```

How it works *(or at least how I think it works)* is that as

```
Given there is a posting
```

is executed, the **posting_step.rb** is invoked (***Factory(:posting) is basically Factory.create(:posting)***), which in turn uses the factory definition I created in **factories.rb**. This leads to an instance of a posting being created.

Then in my **paths.rb**

```
when /the edit posting page/
    edit_posting_path(Posting.first)
```

gets passed the id from the instance, to ultimately get a path that could resemble /posting/1/edit , and the test continues on its way!

If there are any corrections to be made, please let me know as I am just learning the ropes.
Hopefully this will help other newbies out there!

Comment: You're absoloutly right in regards to how it's working. This solution works, but in general the point of acceptance tests is to not bypass things by faking that the edit page is always for the first posting (although it works). You want to use the links/actions available through your website. However, this works and if it's what you go with that's fine.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Thanks for the tidbit!